# How to pass data to client from queue?

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to write tcp-server using `akka-streams`.

I have:

- A Server: when client connects server sends him initiate data. (no problems here)
- A Queue: server fills it periodically. Most of the time it is empty
  (here is a problem)

I want server to send data from queue when it has something.
How can i do it?

Comment: If you have many connections, do you want them to all send the data from the same (shared) queue, or do you want to have a separate 'outgoing queue' for each connection?

Comment: @Arnout Engelen first case, shared queue, queue can be an actor, it doesn't matter, i want to paste infinity source into flow

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I've got the idea that lies behind your problem the right way, but you possibly can go with [Source.Queue](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/queue.html) to obtain the desired behavior.